# Hive Query- Joining two tables on three joining conditions with OR operator

Tags: hive

I am facing an error

"`FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Line 1:101 OR not supported in JOIN currently dob`"

while running the below mentioned query..

```
Insert Overwrite Local Directory './Insurance_Risk/Merged_Data' Select f.name,s.age,f.gender,f.loc,f.marital_status,f.habits1,f.habits2,s.employement_status,s.occupation_class,s.occupation_subclass,s.occupation from sample_member_detail s Join fb_member_detail f 
On s.email=f.email or 
s.dob=f.dob 
or (f.name=s.name and f.loc = s.loc and f.occupation=s.occupation)
where s.email is not null and f.email is not null;
```

Can anyone tell me that, in hive "`OR`" operator can be used or not?
if not, then what should be the query which will give the same result as given by the above mentioned query.
I have 2 tables and I want to join the two tables on any one of the three conditions with or operator.
Please help..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry Hive supports only equi-joins. You can always try select from full Cartesian product of those tables(you have to be in non-strict mode):

```
Select f.name,s.age,f.gender,f.loc,f.marital_status,f.habits1,f.habits2,s.employement_status,s.occupation_class,s.occupation_subclass,s.occupation 
from sample_member_detail s join fb_member_detail f 
where (s.email=f.email 
or s.dob=f.dob 
or (f.name=s.name and f.loc = s.loc and f.occupation=s.occupation))
and s.email is not null and f.email is not null;
```

Answer (score 8):

You could also use UNION to get the same results:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY './Insurance_Risk/Merged_Data' 
-- You can only UNION on subqueries
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT f.name,
        s.age,
        f.gender,
        f.loc,
        f.marital_status,
        f.habits1,
        f.habits2,
        s.employement_status,
        s.occupation_class,
        s.occupation_subclass,
        s.occupation 
    FROM sample_member_detail s 
    JOIN fb_member_detail f 
    ON s.email=f.email 
    WHERE s.email IS NOT NULL AND f.email IS NOT NULL;

    UNION

    SELECT f.name,
        s.age,
        f.gender,
        f.loc,
        f.marital_status,
        f.habits1,
        f.habits2,
        s.employement_status,
        s.occupation_class,
        s.occupation_subclass,
        s.occupation 
    FROM sample_member_detail s 
    JOIN fb_member_detail f 
    ON s.dob=f.dob
    WHERE s.email IS NOT NULL AND f.email IS NOT NULL;

    UNION

    SELECT f.name,
        s.age,
        f.gender,
        f.loc,
        f.marital_status,
        f.habits1,
        f.habits2,
        s.employement_status,
        s.occupation_class,
        s.occupation_subclass,
        s.occupation 
    FROM sample_member_detail s 
    JOIN fb_member_detail f 
    ON f.name=s.name AND f.loc = s.loc AND f.occupation=s.occupation
    WHERE s.email IS NOT NULL AND f.email IS NOT NULL;

) subquery;
```

Comment: You would have to add a _distinct_ on the outer level to get the same results. Otherwise you'll get duplicates of rows that meet multiple conditions.