# how to write a Hive query that filter a table based on another table?

Tags: hive

I have two tables, table One has two columns a and b, and table Two has two columns c and d. For every row in table One, if I can find a row in table Two so that `a = c and substring(b, 1, 3) = substring(d, 1, 3),` then I keep this row in table One. At the end, I want to calculate how many rows are there in table One. I tried to write such a query below but I'm not sure if it's correct?

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM
(SELECT One.a
 FROM One
 LEFT SEMI JOIN Two
 ON One.a  = Two.b
 AND One.ds = '2018-02-27'
 AND Two.ds = '2018-02-27'
 AND One.c IS NOT NULL
 AND Two.d IS NOT NULL
 AND SUBSTR(One.c, 1, 3) = SUBSTR(Two.d, 1, 3)
 GROUP BY One.a) subquery
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I have no data example, I find it quite hard to judge whether your code is correct. However, as I see it you want to join based on two conditions, right?

Some time ago I saw this: [Hive Query- Joining two tables on three joining conditions with OR operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272804/hive-query-joining-two-tables-on-three-joining-conditions-with-or-operator)

I think they have some different options for your there. I had a similar question to what you had, and found the answers very helpful!