# HIVE CONDITIONAL JOIN

Tags: hive

I have a query need to be converted into HIVE query ..the query is like below...

select (some columns)
LEFT JOIN Acercross.Acercross_db_client_master dp 
ON
TRIM(UPPER(dp.cm_blsavingcd)) = TRIM(UPPER(CM.Cl_Code)) 
OR
TRIM(UPPER(dp.cm_cd))=TRIM(UPPER(CM.Cl_Code ))
OR
TRIM(UPPER(dp.cm_cd)) = TRIM(UPPER(CM.CltDpId1)) 
OR 
TRIM(UPPER(dp.cm_cd)) = TRIM(UPPER(CM.CltDpId2))
OR 
TRIM(UPPER(dp.cm_cd)) = TRIM(UPPER(CM.CltDpId3))

when i am running this query i am getting 
Line 35:54 OR not supported in JOIN currently 'CltDpId3'

How to write above query in HIVE.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272804/hive-query-joining-two-tables-on-three-joining-conditions-with-or-operator

Comment: below this query there are 3 other joins statements  also there.if i am using where clause than m not able to write other joins statement.